# Mapping a Dynamic JSON : map a Json data to an object in dart flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Is there any Library or plugin to convert json data to object in Dart (Flutter) like Jackson for example ?

Comment: Not generically, but there are tools for extracting information to and from classes using editor plugins and/or source filters.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json